# How to get custom jquery validation messages for multiple generated fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation on a form that contains a number of SELECT items.  The form is dynamically generated, so I don't know ahead of time how many items there will be.  All I want to do is be sure that each SELECT has a non-empty value, so giving each SELECT a `required` style and letting `validate()` do its thing is all that I need.

This is currently working nicely, except that validation failures produce the standard boring "This field is required" message.  I'd like to substitute something more specific, but I can't figure out how to specify that message, such that it will be produced for all the SELECTs that need it.  I suppose I could generate a string containing the `messages` clause for the validation handler, with one line for each SELECT, and insert it into the handler, but there has to be a more rational way to do this.  Right?  Any suggestions for what that might be?  Thanks!

Comment: Each `select` gets a unique message?  Or all `select` elements will get the same custom message?  Also, please show your relevant code.

Comment: How are you generating the SELECT dynamically ???? you can generate the select like this <select id="ddlGrade" name="ddlGrade" class="form-control" data-rule-required='true' data-msg-required="Grade is required!"></select> so you need to provide (data-msg-required="Grade is required!" ) attribute.

Comment: @Lucky -- I'm generating the form with some PHP, but, in any case, the data-msg-required thing works great.  If you redo this as an actual answer, I'll be happy to accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you generating the SELECT dynamically ???? you can generate the select like this

```
<select id="ddlGrade" name="ddlGrade" class="form-control" data-rule-required='true' data-msg-required="Grade is required!"></select>
```

so you need to provide (data-msg-required="Grade is required!" ) attribute.